# Cannot emulate F# worker role

Tags: f#, azure-cloud-services

I use VisualStudio 2013.4 with Azure .NET SDK 2.5 :

- File / New Project : Azure Cloud Service
- Add F# WorkerRole
- F5

The cloud service cannot start in emulator :

```
    [fabric] Role Instance: deployment25(22).AzureCloudService2.WorkerRole1.0
    [fabric] Role state Unhealthy
    [runtime] Role entrypoint . CALLING   OnStart(): Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.DefaultEntryPoint
    [runtime] Role entrypoint . COMPLETED OnStart(): Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.DefaultEntryPoint
    [runtime] Role entrypoint . CALLING   Run(): Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.DefaultEntryPoint
    [runtime] Role entrypoint . COMPLETED Run() ==> ROLE RECYCLING INITIATED: Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.DefaultEntryPoint
    [runtime] Role instance recycling is starting
    [runtime] Role entrypoint . CALLING   OnStop(): Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.DefaultEntryPoint
    [runtime] Role entrypoint . CALLING   OnStopping()
    [runtime] Role entrypoint . COMPLETED OnStop(): Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.DefaultEntryPoint
    [runtime] Role entrypoint . CALLING   OnStart(): Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.DefaultEntryPoint
    [runtime] Role entrypoint . COMPLETED OnStart(): Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.DefaultEntryPoint
    [runtime] Role entrypoint . CALLING   Run(): Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.DefaultEntryPoint
    [runtime] Role entrypoint . COMPLETED Run() ==> ROLE RECYCLING INITIATED: Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.DefaultEntryPoint
    [runtime] Role instance recycling is starting
    ...
    [fabric] Role state Unhealthy
    [fabric] Role state Suspended
    [fabric] Role state Busy
    [fabric] Role state Unhealthy
    [fabric] Role state Suspended
    ...
```

It works like a charm with C# Worker Role.

Thx in advance for your help

ded'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to manually bundle FSharp.Core with the worker project (ensure CopyLocal is true) or use the FSharp.Core nuget package.

I've seen this with full deploys but not necessarily with the emulator.

Which version of the Azure SDK / Emulator are you using (and Visual Studio)?

Comment: Thanks for helping Isaac. I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Update 4 and Azure .NET SDK 2.5 (both latest versions AFAIK).
If I need to bundle FSharp.Core manually, I'd better use a C# Worker Role that depends on my F# assemblies ?

Comment: Your F# assemblies will still need FSharp.Core.dll to be deployed.

Comment: Well it does not work with F# worker role even with CopyLocal enabled. But it works fine with a C# worker role wrapping my F# code. Thanks again Isaac & Tarmil for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with the F# template, looking to update in the next week or so.