# Cannot emulate C# Worker role

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio-2015, azure-cloud-services, azure-emulator

I have a C# worker role that created with VS2013. This was working fine for more then a year.

I recently upgraded my VS to version **2015** (+**Azure SDK 2.7**) and now when I trying to emulate my code with Azure emulator OR upload this code to the cloud, I have a problem:

```
[fabric] Role Instance: deployment27(109).***.***.0
[fabric] Role state Busy
[runtime] Role entrypoint . CALLING   OnStart(): Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.DefaultEntryPoint
[runtime] Role entrypoint . COMPLETED OnStart(): Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.DefaultEntryPoint
[runtime] Role entrypoint . CALLING   Run(): Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.DefaultEntryPoint
[runtime] Role entrypoint . COMPLETED Run() ==> ROLE RECYCLING INITIATED: Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.DefaultEntryPoint
[runtime] Role instance recycling is starting
[runtime] Role entrypoint . CALLING   OnStop(): Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.DefaultEntryPoint
[runtime] Role entrypoint . CALLING   OnStopping()
[runtime] Role entrypoint . COMPLETED OnStop(): Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.DefaultEntryPoint
[fabric] Role state Unhealthy
[fabric] Role state Suspended
[fabric] Role state Busy
[fabric] Role state Unhealthy
[runtime] Role entrypoint . CALLING   OnStart(): Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.DefaultEntryPoint
[runtime] Role entrypoint . COMPLETED OnStart(): Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.DefaultEntryPoint
[runtime] Role entrypoint . CALLING   Run(): Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.DefaultEntryPoint
[runtime] Role entrypoint . COMPLETED Run() ==> ROLE RECYCLING INITIATED: Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.DefaultEntryPoint
[runtime] Role instance recycling is starting
[runtime] Role entrypoint . CALLING   OnStop(): Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.DefaultEntryPoint
[runtime] Role entrypoint . CALLING   OnStopping()
[runtime] Role entrypoint . COMPLETED OnStop(): Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.DefaultEntryPoint
[runtime] Role entrypoint . CALLING   OnStart(): Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.DefaultEntryPoint
[runtime] Role entrypoint . COMPLETED OnStart(): Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.DefaultEntryPoint
[runtime] Role entrypoint . CALLING   Run(): Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.DefaultEntryPoint
[runtime] Role entrypoint . COMPLETED Run() ==> ROLE RECYCLING INITIATED: Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.DefaultEntryPoint
[runtime] Role instance recycling is starting
[runtime] Role entrypoint . CALLING   OnStop(): Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.DefaultEntryPoint
[runtime] Role entrypoint . CALLING   OnStopping()
[runtime] Role entrypoint . COMPLETED OnStop(): Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.DefaultEntryPoint
[fabric] Role state Busy
[fabric] Role state Suspended
[runtime] Role entrypoint . CALLING   OnStart(): Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.DefaultEntryPoint
[runtime] Role entrypoint . COMPLETED OnStart(): Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.DefaultEntryPoint
[runtime] Role entrypoint . CALLING   Run(): Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.DefaultEntryPoint
[runtime] Role entrypoint . COMPLETED Run() ==> ROLE RECYCLING INITIATED: Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.DefaultEntryPoint
[runtime] Role instance recycling is starting
[runtime] Role entrypoint . CALLING   OnStop(): Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.DefaultEntryPoint
[runtime] Role entrypoint . CALLING   OnStopping()
[runtime] Role entrypoint . COMPLETED OnStop(): Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.DefaultEntryPoint
[fabric] Role state Busy
[fabric] Role state Unhealthy
[fabric] Role state Suspended
[fabric] Role state Busy
[runtime] Role entrypoint . CALLING   OnStart(): Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.DefaultEntryPoint
[runtime] Role entrypoint . COMPLETED OnStart(): Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.DefaultEntryPoint
[runtime] Role entrypoint . CALLING   Run(): Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.DefaultEntryPoint
[runtime] Role entrypoint . COMPLETED Run() ==> ROLE RECYCLING INITIATED: Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.DefaultEntryPoint
[runtime] Role instance recycling is starting
[runtime] Role entrypoint . CALLING   OnStop(): Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.DefaultEntryPoint
[runtime] Role entrypoint . CALLING   OnStopping()
[runtime] Role entrypoint . COMPLETED OnStop(): Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.DefaultEntryPoint
[runtime] Role entrypoint . CALLING   OnStart(): Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.DefaultEntryPoint
[runtime] Role entrypoint . COMPLETED OnStart(): Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.DefaultEntryPoint
[runtime] Role entrypoint . CALLING   Run(): Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.DefaultEntryPoint
[runtime] Role entrypoint . COMPLETED Run() ==> ROLE RECYCLING INITIATED: Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.DefaultEntryPoint
[runtime] Role instance recycling is starting
[runtime] Role entrypoint . CALLING   OnStop(): Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.DefaultEntryPoint
[runtime] Role entrypoint . CALLING   OnStopping()
[runtime] Role entrypoint . COMPLETED OnStop(): Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.DefaultEntryPoint
[fabric] Role state Suspended
[fabric] Role state Busy
[fabric] Role state Unhealthy
[fabric] Role state Suspended
[fabric] Role state Busy
```

You can read in this log that the worker got some problems on Startup. Therefore, the startup failed (then calling OnStop...). This loop never ends.

I was tried to understand where is the problem but found nothing. I tried to debug the code by inserting break-points on: Run, RunAsync, OnStart and OnStop. This was helpless, since those breakpoints was never fired in the application life cycle.

I'm was reading [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28610231/cannot-emulate-f-worker-role) that this problem is well known with F#, but I'm not working with F#.

Comment: Take a look at the FAQ here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-dotnet-diagnostics/.  I had a similar issue with an upgrade to the 2.7 SDK, which I tracked down to being an issue with the way diagnostics work in your role.  Try deleting the `diagnostics.wad*` under the role, and re-enabling diagnostics.